# Определить пересечение UIElement'ов

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть 2 контрола (может быть `rectangle`, `ellipse`, `polygon`) и мне нужно определить пересекаются ли они. Как это сделать?

Comment: Для эллипса вы хотите пересечение именно с эллипсом, или с окружающим прямоугольником?

Comment: А нет уникальной команды вообще для всех графических элементов, типа как intersection у rectangle ? @VladD

Comment: Насколько мне известно, нету. Подождём, может у кого-то будут идеи.

Comment: Возможно, у вас просто неправильный подход. Какая ваша _настоящая_ задача?

Comment: Я хотел сделать что то типа Blueprint из UE4, и остановился на том что  модули должны соединяться между собой при помощи Line, на концах которого весят ellipse, а ellips служит как детектор, что конец line-а находится на входе у другого модуля @VladD

Comment: Я не вполне в курсе того, что такое UE4, но кажется, что ваши фигуры являются модельными объектами. Это значит, что вам придётся не полагаться на встроенные графические примитивы, а обсчитывать их координаты самому в модели.

Comment: https://answers.unrealengine.com/storage/attachments/125-arraybp.jpg @VladD

Comment: у наследников Shape есть .RenderedGeometry. чтобы получить пересечение с другим Geometry надо вызвать FillContainsWithDetail -- вернет IntersectionDetail

Comment: Пробовал, у меня почему-то всегда IntersectionDetail.Intersect возвращался :(
Посмотрите пожалуйста, может line мешает?
http://saveimg.ru/pictures/02-01-16/7198b5723d3c11ed560ff858e808bb9a.png

Comment: Я только что попробовал вообще не создавать line, но IntersectionDetail.Intersect так и возвращается :(((((, как думаете что это может быть, canvas что ли? но а без canvas программа уже не программа... @Stack

Comment: @alexrudenkiy shape'ы на canvas'e и для каждого shape'а указан свой left и top в рамках canvas'а?

Comment: http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0102/h_1451754513_2591769_11152223b1.png @Stack

Comment: @alexrudenkiy рис. вижу. надо выяснить: линия пересекается с каким-то из shape'ов?

Comment: Почти ) ... надо чтобы он определил, что соприкасается ли он с ellipse у которого tag == "in", http://storage5.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0102/h_1451755291_7708936_bc0f530143.png @Stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пересечение фигур, включая линии, можно получить так

```
var g = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Intersect, g1, g2);
```

Работающий пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483495/196972).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Вообще задача чисто математическая и можно ее решить соответственным образом. 
можно рассмотреть на примере окружности (частный случай элипса) и отрезка AB (квадрат и полигоны легко можно разбить на отрезки).

Уравнение для окружности с центром в координатах Хо и Yо выглядит следующим образом:
(X - Xo)^2 + (Y - Yo)^2 = R^2  (^2 - в квадрате)

Уравнение отрезка с координатами A(Xa, Ya) и B(Xb, Yb) выглядит следующим образом:
Y = [(Yb - Ya)/(Xb - Xa)] * (X - Xa) + Ya

Соответственно решив систему из этих двух уравнений можно понять, пересекаются ли элементы. Если система имеет хотя бы одно решение - пересекаются, если нет - не пересекаются.

В вашем случае вместо окружности - элипс, но и они легко описываются уравнениями ([wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81)). Прямоугольники и полигоны - разбиваются на отрезки. 
Решив все системы уравнений можно сделать вывод, какие объекты пересекаются.

Как-то так.

Comment: Вообще-то, пересечение двух эллипсов даёт уравнение четвёртой степени. А если по дороге ещё будут кривые Безье...

Comment: @VladD можно решать и программно с приближениями до нужного уровня точности. Конечно, сложность зависит от "кривости" кривых, тут на усмотрение разработчика)