# Как найти пересечение двух фигур?

Tags: c#, wpf

В Grid есть несколько фигур (производные Shape).
Как получить пересечение двух фигур?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пересечение фигур можно получить с помощью класса CombinedGeometry.

Ниже пример программы, в которой выводится пересечение разных фигур, включая линии. 
Пересечение вычисляется и выводится при движении мыши. Работает быстро. Для примера, между кадрами анимированного gif установлена задержка 500 миллисекунд. 

 
 
 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
// Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.1.0.51204
#r "PresentationFramework"
#r "WindowsBase"
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
```

---

```
// находит пересечение двух фигур, включая линии/отрезки
static CombinedGeometry RenderedIntersect(Visual ctx, Shape s1, Shape s2) {
    var p = new Pen(Brushes.Transparent, 0.01);
    var t1 = s1.TransformToAncestor(ctx) as Transform;
    var t2 = s2.TransformToAncestor(ctx) as Transform;
    var g1 = s1.RenderedGeometry;
    var g2 = s2.RenderedGeometry;
    if (s1 is Line) g1 = g1.GetWidenedPathGeometry(p);
    if (s2 is Line) g2 = g2.GetWidenedPathGeometry(p);
    g1.Transform = t1;
    g2.Transform = t2;
    return new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Intersect, g1, g2);
}
```

---

```
// UI для демонстрации использования RenderedIntersect
var grid = new Grid();
grid.Children.Add(new Line { X1=50, Y1=5, X2=140, Y2=140, Stroke=Brushes.Silver });
grid.Children.Add(new Line { X1=20, Y1=110, X2=270, Y2=50, Stroke=Brushes.Silver });
grid.Children.Add(new Ellipse { Stroke=Brushes.Silver, Width=120, Height=60 });
var g = Geometry.Parse("M200.86114,56.658088 L21.55462,90.649919 114.93742,121.69634 z");
grid.Children.Add(new Path { Stroke = Brushes.Silver, Data = g });
var wnd = new Window() { Width = 300, Height = 200, Content = grid };
```

---

```
// функция выбора двух фигур
Shape p = null;
var nextPair = new Func<Shape[]>(() => {
    var shapes = grid.Children.OfType<Shape>();
    var arr = (from s1 in shapes 
               from s2 in shapes 
               where s1 != s2 select new[] { s1, s2 }).ToArray();
    var rnd = new Random();
    return arr[rnd.Next(0, arr.Length)];
});
```

---

```
// выводим пересечение фигур при движении мыши
var m = 0;
wnd.MouseMove += (s, e) => {
    if (p != null) grid.Children.Remove(p);
    var sa = nextPair();
    var g = RenderedIntersect(grid, sa[0], sa[1]);
    p = new Path() { Stroke = Brushes.Red, StrokeThickness = 2, Data = g };
    grid.Children.Add(p);
};
wnd.ShowDialog();
```