# Пересечение двух Image в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеем два Image, которые перемещаются по экрану, по таймеру. 
Что делать с точки зрения "человечьего" понятно. 
Как это написать на C# с его Canvas?

---

Две картинки, находятся в Canvas. Перемещаются по таймеру. При достижении границ экрана, меняют свое движение в противоположную сторону.

Enot.bubble

Ech.bubble //Обращение к картинкам, находящимся в Canvas

Comment: как перемещаются? определена какая-то траектория? надо определять момент пересечения?

Comment: Случайно появляются при запуске. Отталкиваются от границ экрана. Нужно поймать момент, когда они пересекаются и сделать отталкивание уже друг от друга.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В WPF пересечение фигур можно получить с помощью класса [CombinedGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry(v=vs.110).aspx).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример на C# -- [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483495/196972)

Comment: Можно конкретно для моего примера?

Comment: @Viewed _"Можно конкретно для моего примера?"_ -- можно. но позже. только добавьте в вопрос все основные моменты задачи.

Comment: Хорошо, буду ждать