# Как проверить, пересекаются ли два данных эллипса?

Tags: c#, wpf

Если проверка пересечения двух прямоугольников делается так:

```
ERect.IntersectsWith(EchRect);
```

А установка нового положения для прямоугольника так:

```
ERect.Location = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(bubble), Canvas.GetTop(bubble));
```

То как сделать аналогичную операцию для двух эллипсов?

Comment: посмотрите тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489531/198316, похоже это как раз ваш случай

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Берёте 2 центра прямоугольников `(x1, y1) и (x2, y2)`. Находите тангенс угла между ними

```
tangens = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

По тангенсу определяете радиус, который имеет эллипс при данном угле. Для этого вычисляете косинус и синус угла.

```
cosinus = sqrt( 1 / (tangens*tangens + 1))
sinus = sqrt( 1 - cosinus*cosinus )
```

Модуль косинуса изменяется от 0 в точке `(x1, h1-y1)` до 1 в точке `(w1-x1, y1)`. При этом радиус изменяется от `y1top-y1` до `x1right-x1`, где `h1` - высота прямоугольника 1, а `w1` - длина прямоугольника 1.

Но радиус изменяется не линейно, а по эллиптической кривой, и его можно вычислить по формуле:

```
radius1 = abs(w1-x1)*abs(h1-y1) / sqrt( (h1-y1)*(h1-y1)*cosinus*cosinus + (w1-x1)*(w1-x1)*sinus*sinus )
radius2 = abs(w2-x2)*abs(h2-y2) / sqrt( (h2-y2)*(h2-y2)*cosinus*cosinus + (w2-x2)*(w2-x2)*sinus*sinus )
```

где `radius1` - радиус первого прямоугольника, `radius2` - радиус второго прямоугольника.

Вычисляете расстояние между центрами:

```
rasstoyanie = sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1))
```

Если `rasstoyanie` меньше или равно суммы `radius1+radius2`, то эллипсы пересекаются. Если `rasstoyanie` больше суммы `radius1+radius2`, то эллипсы не пересекаются.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! В моем случае оказалось даже чуть-чуть попроще.