# Как сделать так, чтобы при движении одного объекта на другой он не пересек его?

Tags: c#, form, формы

Есть два объекта, рисуемые на форме (на пример, круг и треугольник) и необходимо при движение (движение происходит при нажатии стрелок на клавиатуре) треугольника на круг, или наоборот, сделать так, чтобы треугольник не пересек круг, но при этом не помещать его в pictureBox (чтобы у объектов не было рамки)?

Comment: Может быть [это](https://toster.ru/q/454082) будет полезно

Comment: можно узнать, пересекаются ли фигуры или нет, как указано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483494/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно вычислить, существует ли пересечение.

Например для отрезка (стороны треугольника) найти, есть ли пересечение с окружностью (т.е. точки, удовлетворяющие условию `(x-cx)^2+(y-cy)^2=r^2`)